# Painting code doesn't work properly in my WM_COMMAND message handler

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

I have the following code that is supposed to paint `picture2.bmp` after the user invokes the item `ID_FILE_32771`.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case ID_FILE_32771:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        LoadAndBlitBitmap2(__T("D://picture2.bmp"), hdc);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    LoadAndBlitBitmap(__T("D://picture.bmp"), hdc);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

The problem is, nothing is getting painted. `hdc` is not properly initialized. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` functions are ***only*** to be called when you handle the `WM_PAINT` message. The way you've done it, in handling `WM_COMMAND`, is wrong:

```
case ID_FILE_32771:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);                        // WRONG, WRONG!
        LoadAndBlitBitmap2(__T("D://picture2.bmp"), hdc);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);                                // ALSO WRONG!
        break;
```

*All* of the painting code needs to be inside of the `WM_PAINT` handler. You are going to receive `WM_PAINT` messages whenever you window needs to be painted, and sometimes that's outside of your control. So there needs to be logic in the `WM_PAINT` handler that knows what to paint based on the current state of the application.

In other words, you need to set a flag in response to clicks on `ID_FILE_32771` so that your program knows it should be calling `LoadAndBlitBitmap2` when it repaints itself, instead of `LoadAndBlitBitmap` (why aren't they the same function, to which you simply pass different file names?).

Outside of the `WM_PAINT` handler, you cause a paint event to occur by invalidating the contents of your window. The simplest and most generally appropriate way to do that is by calling the [`InvalidateRect` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002.aspx). For example:

```
case ID_FILE_32771:
        // Set a flag indicating that picture2 should be painted
        // (or some other equivalent mechanism)
        paintPicture2 = true;

        // Signal that the window should be repainted.
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);

        break;
```

By calling [`UpdateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167.aspx) after `InvalidateRect`, you'll force an *immediate* repaint, but this is rarely necessary. Alternatively, you can skip the two-function-dance and call the more powerful [`RedrawWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162911.aspx) directly.

Either way, you'll invoke your `WM_PAINT` message handler, and it will query the application's current status and paint the appropriate picture.

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    // Paint the appropriate thing, depending on the app's current state
    if (paintPicture2)
        LoadAndBlitBitmap(__T("D://picture.bmp"), hdc);
    else
        LoadAndBlitBitmap(__T("D://picture.bmp"), hdc);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

BeginPaint is only to be used in WM_PAINT. You could use GetDC if you need a HDC outside of WM_PAINT. But the better solution is usually to just call InvalidateRect outside of WM_PAINT. That will cause a new WM_PAINT to come in soon and you do all painting in WM_PAINT.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183362):

> An application should not call `BeginPaint` **except in response to a WM_PAINT message**

That is, your fixing is to use the APIs in the supposed way, which is typically invalidating the view via `InvalidateRect` and then painting through `WM_PAINT` when you are requested to.